# Error using sound_play package

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to learn something by using the ALICE code to let it able to speak. I follow the instruction given by the books "Learning robotic using python" in chapter 8. But I have problem on making it speak and also speech recognition.

To make it speak, I am using sound_play package in ROS. Due to the problem, I tested it with:

```
> roslaunch sound_play soundplay_node.launch
```

Then it come out with error as follow:

> .. logging to
> /home/user/.ros/log/bd387f44-f6c5-11e7-ac01-b0359f36d413/roslaunch-user-HP-Laptop-4644.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage.
> This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to
> interrupt Done checking log file disk
> usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server
> http://user-HP-Laptop:36451/
>
> ## SUMMARY
>
> PARAMETERS  * /rosdistro: kinetic  *
> /rosversion: 1.12.7
>
> NODES   /
> soundplay_node (sound_play/soundplay_node.py)
>
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
>
> core service [/rosout] found
> process[soundplay_node-1]: started
> with pid [4662] Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/audio_common/sound_play/scripts/soundplay_node.py",
> line 48, in 
> from sound_play.msg import SoundRequest, SoundRequestAction,
> SoundRequestResult,
> SoundRequestFeedback ImportError: No
> module named sound_play.msg
> [soundplay_node-1] process has died
> [pid 4662, exit code 1, cmd
> /home/user/catkin_ws/src/audio_common/sound_play/scripts/soundplay_node.py
> __name:=soundplay_node __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/bd387f44-f6c5-11e7-ac01-b0359f36d413/soundplay_node-1.log].
> log file:
> /home/user/.ros/log/bd387f44-f6c5-11e7-ac01-b0359f36d413/soundplay_node-1*.log
> all processes on machine have died,
> roslaunch will exit shutting down
> processing monitor... ... shutting
> down processing monitor complete done

I'm not sure why is this happen... Can anyone helps please? TT

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279509/error-using-sound_play-package/) by [Mich K](https://answers.ros.org/users/33243/mich-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have the package cloned into your workspace. The error message is saying, that the message file for python cannot be found. This file is auto-generated once you compile your Workspace.

I guess you just have to call a `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`, whatever build command you use), and if this compiles successfully, you are good to go...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0